# angular no spaces form validation

Tags: angularjs, validation

How would you in angular validate for that a text box has no spaces. Is there a built in expression or would I have to fall back on a regular expression?

For example I would like if a user types in the following into a text input field

Pass/valid:adf

Fail/Dirty:a s d

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need a pattern.  Required is just going to make sure something is in there. I'm sure you've looked at it but for others, Angular docs show the available input validation options:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
ng-pattern="/^\s*\w*\s*$/"
```

this regex evaluates for spaces inside the input